# how to pass dynamique data from child to parent in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to pass the data of text-input from child to parent to submit the dynamic form. when i use useEffect the phone blocked but i don't know why.please can someone help me to solve this problem.thanks to tell me if there are another way to pass the data.

**child component**

```
const RenderComponents = ({ sendChildToParent) => {
    const [inputsVal, setInputsVal] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (name, value) => {
      setInputsVal({ ...inputsVal, [name]: value });
    };

    const senddata = () => {
      sendChildToParent(inputsVal);
    };

    useEffect(senddata);

    return (
      <>
        {getData.length === 0 ? (
          <Empty />
        ) : (
          getData.map((item, index) => {
            switch (item.type) {
              case "TextInput":
                return (
                  <>
                    <InputText
                      onChangeText={(text) => handleChange(item.nameC, text)}
                      ModuleName={item.nameC}
                      placeholder={item.options.placeholder}
                      required={item.options.required}
                      key={index}
                    />
                  </>
                );
              case "Phone":...
```

**Parent Component**

```
export function TemplateScreen(props) {
 
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [getData, setData] = React.useState(Mydata);

  const [childData, setChildData] = useState([]);

  const sendChildToParent = (dataFromChild) => {
    setChildData(dataFromChild);
  };

  //*************************************Child Componenet*************** */
  const RenderComponents = () => {
    const [userTeam, setUserTeam] = useState({});
[...other code here...];

**********Parent Component*******
return (
          <ScrollView>
            <RenderComponents />
            <Button
                title="Submit"
                onPress={()=>null}
              />...
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your parent component is fine. The issues are in your child component, in the following lines:

```js
const RenderComponents = ({ sendChildToParent) => {
    const [inputsVal, setInputsVal] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (name, value) => {
      setInputsVal({ ...inputsVal, [name]: value });
    };

    const senddata = () => {
      sendChildToParent(inputsVal);
    };

    useEffect(senddata);
```

1. it's not good practice to duplicate the input value in local state.  Pass the value down from the parent component as well as the setter function.
2. you're not passing a dependency array to your useEffect function, so it runs on every render of the component.  This sets off the following chain of events:

   - the parent renders
   - the child renders
   - useEffect runs, setting the value of the state in the parent
   - the parent re-renders

   This is an endless loop and what causes your app to lock.
3. there's no need to wrap the state setting functions in your own functions unless you are planning to do additional work there later.  There's also no need to run those functions in your component lifecycle (useEffect), because they will run when the input changes.
4. missing bracket in the first line.

You could rewrite the components in the following way:

```js
// parent component
export function TemplateScreen(props) {
 
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [getData, setData] = React.useState(Mydata);

  const [childData, setChildData] = useState({});

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <RenderComponents childData={childData} setChildData={setChildData} />
      ...

// child component
const RenderComponents = ({ childData, setChildData }) => {
    const handleChange = (name, value) => {
      setChildData({ ...childData, [name]: value });
    };

    return (
      ...
```

Comment: thanks for help. i'm tried this solution but when i press in phone keyboard the keyboard close and reset the value of text input

Comment: There might be something else going on, but if this got you past the locking issue, you could raise a different question.  This implementation is standard for controlled inputs.  Did you pass `childData` to the value of the input?

Comment: yes i pass it to the value of the input